# What is the real difference between EqualsBuilder and &&

Tags: java

Say I have an Object that has 10 different fields. So what is the real different between these two implementations?

Using Apache EqualsBuilder

```
return new EqualsBuilder()
    .append(field1, o.getField1())
    .append(field2, o.getField2())
    ....
    .isEquals();
```

Using Home built

```
return field1.equals(o.getField1())
    && field2.equals(o.getField2())
    ....;
```

Both implementations I have to main new additional fields or remove field when they are refactored. So I am not sure why people think EqualsBuilder is a good implementation?

Comment: What happens when one of your operands is null?

Comment: Not, it is not a duplicate because I am asking what is he difference, meaning I am asking performance and design best practice. So far from reading that post, I only get the feel that everything home grown is bad and using the framework is good without any actual reason.

Comment: @Gabe that would be something I encapsulate and make sure that is something I would check. Look at my comment to Elliott Frisch's Answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [`EqualsBuilder` Javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) says (in part with emphasis added),

> This class provides methods to build a good equals method for any class. It follows rules laid out in [Effective Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/effectivejava-136174.html), by Joshua Bloch. In particular the rule for comparing **`doubles`**, **`floats`**, and **`arrays`** can be tricky. Also, making sure that **`equals()`** and **`hashCode()`** are consistent can be difficult.

Comment: What I found equalsBuild to be most troublesome is the lack of ability to expand on the comparison. For example. What if I need the string comparison to render an equal if one field is blank and the comparing object has a null.

Comment: example: `return StringUtils.isNotBlank(a) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(b) ? StringUtils.equals(a, b) : StringUtils.isBlank(a.trim()) && StringUtils.isBlank(b.trim());`

Comment: @Churk When building your search method I would transform a null to a blank... or use a pattern matcher instead.

Answer (score 0):

`field1.equals(o.getField1())` is good only for Object fields, it wont work for primitives